# Image path file not found

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, filenotfoundexception

I have spent quite a while trying to solve this problem, but to no avail.  I have searched stackoverflow as well as Google and have not been able to resolve my (seemingly) simple problem.

I am getting a FileNotFoundException in the following line:

```
Image.FromFile("\\Resources\\Icons\\key-icon.png");
```

The folders and image are really there, and I can't see what the problem is.

Comment: Is the picture is really at c:\Resources\Icons\key-icon.png ?

Comment: Check this anwser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269570/filenotfoundexception-iis7 . Maybe it is same problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should consider that it is started from "yourproject/bin/Release" so you need to go up 2 directories. Do this:

```
Image.FromFile("..\\..\\Resources\\Icons\\key-icon.png");
```

Comment: This solved the problem! Is there a way to just make the solution start from the root?

Comment: Yes if you delete the project property output path. Current content has to be `bin\Release\` but this could look ugly since you would compile code into your project's root folder. edit: wait test it I am not sure if this can be changed, could be that it is started from bin\Debug\ aswell.

Answer (score 4):

Try using an absolute path not a relative one... i.e.

```
Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(@"~\Resources\Icons\key-icon.png"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                            @"Resources\\Icons\\key-icon.png"))
```

Base-directory Combine your file-name

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a leading ".":

```
Image.FromFile(".\\Resources\\Icons\\key-icon.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Internally, `Image.FromFile` uses `File.Exists` to check whether the file exists. This method returns `false` when:

- the file does not exist (makes sense)
- the current process identity does not have permission to read the file

It may be that the second option is your problem.

And another possibility: is `Resources` a network share? In that case you should use the following:

```
Image.FromFile("\\\\Resources\\Icons\\key-icon.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case I discovered that sikuli does not automatically detect the root folder of the project. What you should do for this case is specify the folder using the command `System.getProperty("user.dir");`

```
import org.sikuli.script.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Screen s = new Screen();
            try{
                    String pathYourSystem = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\";
                    s.click(pathYourSystem + "imgs/spotlight.png");
                    //s.wait(pathYourSystem + "imgs/spotlight-input.png");
                    //s.click();
                    s.write("hello world#ENTER.");
            }
            catch(FindFailed e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```