# Cant find image in network drive

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-mvc-4, networking, file-io

I know this question have been asking many times but none of then have solved my situation.

I have this simple code

```
   Image f = Image.FromFile(@"\\NetWork\imagenes\folder0\1690D-PC.tif");
```

But it throws:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException \\NetWork\imagenes\folder0\1690D-PC.tif
```

1. **I have total access** to the related network
2. **I do can find the image in that location**. I copy the path, START + r, pasted the path and the image opens.
3. Is the same for all images in that server.

But the situation not only remains there:

1. I tested in another pc to checked if is was a IIS problem or
   whatever, but when I tested it throws the same(2 pc cannot access to
   that file, having they full access... weird...)
2. *When im in development, I can find the image everything work normaly*, but **when i deploy and
   upload to my local iis and the other pc, throw the related exception**(FileNotFoundException).
3. My parner has the same code(almost the same proyect, just with some
   diferrent functionality and public) and he can find the image and
   display it.

I ran into this situation last friday and i havent came up with a solution yet.

Im willing to hear all your suggestions.

**Update 2.
More info:**

There are 2 more application that request images from that server and those application can find it normally. *Those application are in my local IIS.*

Updte

Tracktrace

```
[FileNotFoundException: \\DAVID-PC\imagenes\folder0\1690D-PC.tif]
   System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement) +472351
   System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename) +6
   Muckup.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\Users\pkm\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Muckup\Muckup\Controllers\HomeController.cs:20
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +211
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +223
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514812
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: What's the inner exception say? Usually these things end up being Access Denied due to one permissions issue or another.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269570/filenotfoundexception-iis7) The problem looks similar...

Comment: updated, tracktrace added

Comment: This issue can only solved by you, by troubleshooting. As which user is the application pool running for your and the working applications? Does your user have the proper permissions for the path?  Is the path you show the actual path, or do you use drive mappings? Does the working application use the exact same path?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using double back slashes instead of @ to find the file? Might be worth trying.

```
 Image f = Image.FromFile(" *FullPath* \\NetWork\\imagenes\\folder0\\1690D-PC.tif");
```

Comment: Not, not luck. Im still investigating but nothing seems to work.