# Impossible to get image from network drive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, networking, file-io

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235018/cant-find-image-in-network-drive/21236791)(**please** read it to fully understand) and im still unable to find a solution. I took a newly empty create project and paste that code and the same error occurred: Cannot find the image.

Well I took that project and gave it to 4 of my workmates (since I thought it could be an IIS permission issue) and they upload that the newly create project to their respective IIS and the same error is being thrown, just one of then could get the image. This is the only code that the project contains:

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(@"\\jmojica-pc\Publico\IMAGENES\RIEGOS_GENERALES\0", "1JMojica-pc.tif");

             FileStream fin = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            return View();
        }

    }
```

NOTE: I can find the image in that location. I copy the path, START + r, pasted the path and the image opens.

4 of our support where trying to get a solution because they thought it could be a permisson issue but nothing worked.

Here is the list of exception got from different code. All of the use the same path:

1. `Image image = Image.FromFile(path)` FileNotFoundException
2. `var stream = new MemoryStream(path);` Acccess denied
3. `using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(path)){
   } // Invalid Parameter`

Im totally lost, I dont know what could be the cause.

Maybe is my pc? No, I tried in anothers pc with theirs own IIS and the same problem.

Maybe the code? Come on, thats only one line of code and does not work anywhere!

Am I curse? Im staring to belive that i have a son around that i dont know and some unnatural power is punishing me for that.

Comment: It's probably a permissions issue.  The default IIS principal won't have access to the network share.

Comment: My user have full access to that directory.

Comment: IIS does not, by default,  use the identity of the person logged in.  It uses its own principal.  *You* might have full access, but IIS uses a service account and won't have access.  Change the app pool settings to use a domain identity.

Comment: I am having this exact issue. any answer?

Comment: If your running your application through IIS, and not visual studio, add IIS_IUSRS under security tab in properties of that folder and grant read permissions.